# R: Save Each For-Loop Iteration As New Named List inside List

Tags: r, for-loop, tibble

I have a for-loop that extracts equal-length numerical ranges and appends each range as a new list within a list.  After the for-loop completes I want to turn the list of lists into a data frame and calculate the row means.  I currently cannot convert the list of lists to a tibble, because the individual lists are not named.

How can I name each of the new lists as the integer associated with the loop iteration? (i.e. 1, 2, 3 ...)

Simplified example below. My actual for loop does something more complicated, but it captures the issue I'm having.

Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)

input_df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("A", "B", "C"),
  Start = c(100,250,350),
  Stop = c(150,300,400)
  )

All_list <- list()

for(i in 1:length(input_df$Name)) {
  
  myoutput <- data.frame(
    Value=seq.int(paste0(input_df$Start[i]), paste0(input_df$Stop[i]))
  )

#How do I specify that the name of added list is the value of the iteration [i]?
  All_list[[i]] <- myoutput$Value
}

All_df <- All_list %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Average = mean(c_across(1:length(myvector)))) %>%
  ungroup()

Error in `as_tibble()`:
! Columns 1, 2, and 3 must be named.
Use `.name_repair` to specify repair.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're loading `tidyverse`, you can rewrite your loop using [`purrr:pmap()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/pmap.html) to map over each row simultaneously. We can `rename()` the columns to `from` and `to` so they are provided to `seq.int()` by `pmap()`:

```r
out_df  <- input_df |>
    rename(from = Start, to = Stop) |>
    pmap(seq.int) |>
    set_names(input_df$Name)     |>
    as_tibble()

head(out_df, 3)
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#       A     B     C
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1   100   250   350
# 2   101   251   351
# 3   102   252   352
```

The output is a named list identical to the one created by your loop, where we can `set_names()` to the `Name` column of `input_df` and make into a `tibble()`.

I think you're then trying to calculate the average by row. You can use the base `rowMeans()` function for this:

```r
out_df   %>% 
    mutate(Average = rowMeans(.))
# # A tibble: 51 × 4
#        A     B     C Average
#    <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>
#  1   100   250   350    233.
#  2   101   251   351    234.
#  3   102   252   352    235.
```

Incidentally you can get these means in a one-liner in base R:

```r
rowMeans(apply(input_df, 1, \(row) seq(row["Start"], row["Stop"])))
# Same output as Average column
```

#### If you must use a loop

In response to your comment, if you have to use a loop, simply set the names when you create the `All_list` variable, prior to your loop. So rather than `All_list <- list()`, you can do:

```r
All_list  <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(input_df))  |>
    setNames(input_df$Name)
```

It is also better to create a list of the length you will need, avoiding the well-known performance bottleneck of growing a vector in R. See p.12 of [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). (Things have improved a bit since then but it's still more efficient to create a list of the required length when it is known in advance.)

Comment: Hi @SamR, is there a way to do this with the for loop structure that I currently have?  In my pipeline the ranges are generated from files that are read-in with the iteration - all range data isn't immediately available for Purr.

Comment: @JVGen see my edit

Answer (score 1):

You can also follow that tip in the error message and use `.name_repair`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# list structure for reference:
str(All_list)
#> List of 3
#>  $ : int [1:51] 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 ...
#>  $ : int [1:51] 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 ...
#>  $ : int [1:51] 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 ...

# use .name_repair and c_across(everything())
All_list %>%
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "universal") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Average = mean(c_across(everything()))) %>%
  ungroup()
#> New names:
#> • `` -> `...1`
#> • `` -> `...2`
#> • `` -> `...3`
#> # A tibble: 51 × 4
#>     ...1  ...2  ...3 Average
#>    <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>
#>  1   100   250   350    233.
#>  2   101   251   351    234.
#>  3   102   252   352    235.
#>  4   103   253   353    236.
#>  5   104   254   354    237.
#>  6   105   255   355    238.
#>  7   106   256   356    239.
#>  8   107   257   357    240.
#>  9   108   258   358    241.
#> 10   109   259   359    242.
#> # ℹ 41 more rows
```

If you just need a vector of sums from your current list, you can bind all vectors in list to a matrix and apply `mean()` :

```
do.call(cbind, All_list) |> apply(1,mean)
#>  [1] 233.3333 234.3333 235.3333 236.3333 237.3333 238.3333 239.3333 240.3333
#>  [9] 241.3333 242.3333 243.3333 244.3333 245.3333 246.3333 247.3333 248.3333
#> [17] 249.3333 250.3333 251.3333 252.3333 253.3333 254.3333 255.3333 256.3333
#> [25] 257.3333 258.3333 259.3333 260.3333 261.3333 262.3333 263.3333 264.3333
#> [33] 265.3333 266.3333 267.3333 268.3333 269.3333 270.3333 271.3333 272.3333
#> [41] 273.3333 274.3333 275.3333 276.3333 277.3333 278.3333 279.3333 280.3333
#> [49] 281.3333 282.3333 283.3333
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>